# postgres error: column doesn't exist error in Postgesql 11.6

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11, quoted-identifier, string-constant

I am trying to run an update command on postgresql 11.6 by below syntax

```
 update "YP_SUPPLIERS" set "YP_SUPPLIERS.supplierName" = "update" where "YP_SUPPLIERS.supplierID" = da68e9d0-1100-43e2-0011-db8fbe654321;
```

I am getting this below error

```
ERROR:  column "YP_SUPPLIERS.supplierID" does not exist
```

LINE 1: ... set "YP_SUPPLIERS.supplierName" = "update" where "YP_SUPPLI...

tired different combinations by only giving the column name , removing the quotes but nothing seems to be working.

Could any one suggest me a right way to do it.

Comment: You should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote each element separately, and the table does not need to be repeated for the target column. String constants need to be enclosed in single quotes (`'`) in SQL. Double quotes are **only** for identifiers.

```
 update "YP_SUPPLIERS" 
     set "supplierName" = 'update' --<< single quotes for constant values
 --     ^ no table name here
 where "YP_SUPPLIERS"."supplierID" = 'da68e9d0-1100-43e2-0011-db8fbe654321';
 --    ^ schema and table name must be quoted separately
```

Comment: It worked. Why is this so complicated is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: It's not complicated at all. You made it complicated when you created your tables with quoted identifiers. If you never use double quotes in SQL, you will have a lot less trouble in the long run.